# Error parsing proxys requests.exceptions.InvalidURL

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.9

estoy intentando usar proxys para python requests, todo iba bien hasta que quise agregar el soporte a proxys rotativas (9KB943cNnY_289:mix;mix;mix:141.98.80.111:5401) y al hacerlo me da el siguiente error :(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\outlook.py", line 80, in <module>
    a()
  File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\outlook.py", line 79, in a
    r1 = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy_form)
  File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: https://9KB943cNnY_289:mix;mix;mix:141.98.80.111:5401
```

No se que hacer, traté de cambiar el formato de las proxis pero aun así no funciona. Este es mi codigo:

```
def a():
    global proxylist    
    load_proxy()
    sess = requests.Session()
    proxy = random.choice(proxylist) #ProxyList is a list of proxys loaded
    proxy_form = {'http': f"http://{proxy}", 'https': f"https://{proxy}"}
    url = "https://test.com"
    r1 = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy_form)
```

Comment: El error parece ser la URL. Si no has puesto "https://test.com" como ejemplo... edita la pregunta y agrega la URL real. Es posible que la url contenga algún carácter o estructura invalida y por eso el error

Comment: Si lees bien la url son las proxys
proxy_form = {'http': f"http://{proxy}", 'https': f"https://{proxy}"}